# multiple scrollview, scrollevent of scrollview1 also triggers scrollevent of scrollsview2 on Android

Tags: android, scrollview, nativescript

In my NativeScript-typescript app I have a screen with 2 ScrollViews on it. Both ScrollViews have a scrollevent. Now when I scroll ScrollView1, also the ScrollEvent of ScrollView2 is fired. At least on Android that's the situation. On iOS only the ScrollView that's being scrolled the scrollevent fires.

**Does anybody have an idea why this is?**

Also the call to scroll() in pageLoaded has no effect on Android. on iOS it works as expected.

**Does anybody have an idea why this is?**

Thanks in advance for your time!

The layout of my screen is as follows :

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
    loaded="pageLoaded"
    actionBarHidden="false">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <ScrollView id="scroller1" orientation="horizontal">
                <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" width="auto" >
                    <Button text="Click me 1" textWrap="true" style="font-size: 12;" height="90" width="550"
                            borderRadius="0" borderWidth="0.1" borderColor="blue" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <ScrollView id="scroller2" orientation="horizontal" >
                <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" width="auto" >
                    <Button text="Click me 4" textWrap="true" style="font-size: 12;" height="90" width="550"
                            borderRadius="0" borderWidth="0.1" borderColor="blue" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout>
            <Button text="click" tap="buttonClicked" />
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

The code-behind is as follows :

```
import { EventData } from "data/observable";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { ScrollView } from "ui/scroll-view";
import observable = require("data/observable");
import scrollViewModule = require("ui/scroll-view")

let scroller1: ScrollView;
let scroller2: ScrollView;

export function pageLoaded(args: EventData) {
    let page = <Page>args.object;

    scroller1 = <ScrollView>page.getViewById("scroller1");
    scroller2 = <ScrollView>page.getViewById("scroller2");

    scroller1.on(ScrollView.scrollEvent, scrollingScroller1, this);
    scroller2.on(ScrollView.scrollEvent, scrollingScroller2, this);

    scroll();
}

export function buttonClicked(args: scrollViewModule.ScrollEventData) {
    scroll();
}

export function scrollingScroller1(args: scrollViewModule.ScrollEventData) {
    console.log('scrollingScroller1');
}
export function scrollingScroller2(args: scrollViewModule.ScrollEventData) {
    console.log('scrollingScroller2');
}

export function scroll() {
    scroller1.scrollToHorizontalOffset(300, false);
    scroller1.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 500
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Johan - I have tested your scenario and indeed under Android both events fires simutaniosly. I have logged this issue at https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2362